# Can a character use 'Paragon Surge' to gain a feat they temporarily qualify for?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, shapeshifting

The current example I am thinking is a Sorcerer casting a spell similar to [Form Of The Dragon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/form-of-the-dragon-i/) causing them to gain natural attacks. Could the Sorcerer in question follow up that spell with [Paragon Surge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/paragon-surge/) and choose [Multi-Attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/multiattack-combat/) as their temporary feat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You cannot be affected by Form of the Dragon and Paragon Surge at the same time.

From the transmutation school rules:

> You can only be affected by one polymorph spell at a time. If a new polymorph spell is cast on you (or you activate a polymorph effect, such as wild shape), you can decide whether or not to allow it to affect you, taking the place of the old spell.

Both [Form of the Dragon](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Form%20of%20the%20Dragon%20I) and [Paragon Surge](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Paragon%20Surge) are transmutation (polymorph), so you cannot be affected by both at the same time. While Paragon Surge has the following rider, it does not override that inherent restrictions of the polymorph subschool, so unfortunately you can't benefit from both spells at once:

> Unlike with most polymorph effects, your basic form does not change, so you keep all extraordinary and supernatural abilities of your half-elven form as well as all of your gear.

As for the general question — can you pick a feat with Paragon Surge that you only qualify for temporarily — it's more of a grey area.

### Temporary bonuses do not qualify for feats, but it's vague for qualities other than ability scores.

Here are the rules for qualifying for a feat:

> Some feats have prerequisites. Your character must have the indicated ability score, class feature, feat, skill, base attack bonus, or other quality designated in order to select or use that feat. A character can gain a feat at the same level at which he gains the prerequisite.
>
> A character can't use a feat if he loses a prerequisite, but he does not lose the feat itself. If, at a later time, he regains the lost prerequisite, he immediately regains full use of the feat that prerequisite enables.

There's an interesting quirk between "temporary" and "permanent" bonuses:

> Permanent Bonuses: Ability bonuses with a duration greater than 1 day actually increase the relevant ability score after 24 hours. Modify all skills and statistics related to that ability. This might cause you to gain skill points, hit points, and other bonuses. These bonuses should be noted separately in case they are removed.

There's an official post from a designer [here](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l4kc&page=2?Feats-Prerequisite#91) ([direct link](https://paizo.com/posts/gbijncq5/favorites)) that adds more context around what qualifies for a feat, particularly with regard to temporary and permanent bonuses:

> 1. The game differentiates between permanent ability score bonuses (such as +1 every 4 character levels and wearing a +2 belt of giant strength for 24 hours) and temporary ability score bonuses (such as from barbarian rage, an alchemist mutagen, or a bull's strength spell).
> 2. Permanent ability score bonuses **do count** for the purpose of qualifying for feats.
> 3. If you lose a permanent ability score bonus, you still have the feat, you just can't use it until your ability score qualifies again.
> 4. Temporary ability score bonuses **do not count** for the purpose of qualifying for feats. (My earlier statement contradicting this point was my opinion of how it should work.)
> 5. I personally believe that differentiating between permanent and temporary scores in this fashion is needlessly complex and only hinders player choices in a metagaming way.
> 6. I personally believe that you could revise the feat prerequisite system so characters could select feats before they actually meet the prerequisites, but wouldn't be able to use the feat until they do, which would allow (for example) monks and rogues to take Weapon Focus at level 1 in anticipation of having the required BAB +1 at level 2.
> 7. Implementing points 5 and 6 as official game rules would require making revisions to language elsewhere in the game (such as qualifying for a prestige class), similar to how the discussion about revising the Stealth skill is a significant change that affects other parts of the rules (such as scent and hide in plain sight).
> 8. The design team hasn't discussed implementing 5 and 6 as official game rules.

There is no official guidance (as far as I know) for how temporary vs. permanent would work for anything other than ability scores, but this is the clearest analogue I'm aware of for qualifying for a feat with a temporary status. There's going to be a degree of DM discretion here since it's not cut and dry, but personally I'd rule that you'd only count as qualifying for a feat if the status is permanent, counting "permanent" as "in effect for at least 24 hours," following the precedent for ability scores.

Comment: You're right on the first part with the polymorph, but wrong on the second part: The rules you quote on temporary vs permanent bonuses is outdated and has been replaced by a FAQ that removes all differences between the two 
https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9rbg

Comment: "A temporary ability score bonus should affect all of the same stats and rolls that a permanent ability score bonus does." It affects the same things, but it doesn't affect them *in the same way*. A temporary strength bonus increases your carrying capacity just like a permanent ability score bonus, but it's still not a permanent bonus.

Comment: Good catch, I missed that both spells are polymorph

Comment: Still false answer. There is NO DIFFERENCE between temporary and permanent bonuses: "Think of it in the same way that a simple template has "quick rules" and "rebuild rules;" they're supposed to create monsters which are roughly equivalent in terms of stats, but the quick rules are a short cut that misses some details compared to using the rebuild rules. Likewise, the temporary ability score rule is intended as a short cut to speed up gameplay, not as the most precise way of applying the bonus." as per the FAQ https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9rbg

Comment: The "quick rules" they mention are "the glossary mentions Strength-based skill checks, melee attack rolls, [...]" and the "rebuild rules" are "You're usually not using the spell for a 1 min./level increase in your carrying capacity, so that isn't mentioned there, but the bonus should still apply to that, as well as to Strength checks to break down doors."

I'll reiterate: "the bonus should still apply to that." This FAQ is addressing the fact that a temporary strength bonus increases everything a permanent bonus does, including carrying capacity. That does not make it a permanent bonus.

Comment: What's the difference between a permanent and temporary bonus? None, I reiterate, the FAQ says that temporary bonuses are just "a short cut to speed up gameplay, not as the most precise way of applying the bonus". In other words, if you want to apply the rules precisely, then use them as permanent bonuses: There is no "temporary" and "permanent" bonus difference in the Pathfinder rules; the former is just a shortcut for faster gameplay but not an actual rule.

Comment: That FAQ is explicitly and exclusively talking in terms of "it was not possible to list every single ability score-related game effect," "the most common game effects relative to that ability score," "the bonus should still apply to that," and "affect all of the same stats and rolls." There is nothing in that FAQ that says that temporary and permanent bonuses are the same — just that they affect the same things — and given the presence of rules that distinguish them, they remain different. I'm not going to continue litigating this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The issue is that as soon as that spell wears off, they still have the feat but it no longer works until all criteria are met. Examples of this are martial feats based on dex or str where they lose access to the feats due to types of damage (or even losing magical gear). Other examples would be casters unable to cast spells because of primary casting score damage, or if a feat required it, a high enough ability score.

Lets say technically you could take any feat you wanted, but it only worked while you fulfilled all its requirements. Thats what happens when you have non-permanent abilities that grant you access to feats.

I actually did something like this for one of my characters. I was a summoner who wore their summon, and took extra limbs. While I had extra limbs I leveled up, and took the multi-attack feat. The feat was only usable when I was wearing the summon and had the extra limbs.

Comment: I mean at least for this particular example, the two spells have pretty much equal durations so it's not really a problem. ^^'